# Email Classifier to classify emails according to the time

Tags: python, pandas

I have to design a program that can classify emails as spam or nonspam using Python and Pandas.

I have done to classify the email as spam or nonspam according to the email's subject. For my second task, I have to classify the emails as spam or nonspam according to the time. If the email gets received on ('Friday and 'Saturday') it should be classified as spam. Otherwise nonspam. I literally don't have any idea how to do that. I tried to search but ended up with nothing.

This is a screenshot from the excel file
[image: Email Table.xlsx]

```
import pandas as pd
ExcelFile = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Documents\Email Table.xlsx')
Subject = pd.DataFrame(ExcelFile, columns=['Subject'])

def spam(Subject):
A = len(ExcelFile[ExcelFile['Subject'].isnull()]) 
print("Number of spam emails ",A)
print(ExcelFile[ExcelFile['Subject'].isnull()]) 

spam(Subject)
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a million ways you could do this, but this is how I would do it. I provided comments and some naming conventions simply for clarity which should allow you to take and modify as necessary to fit your specific needs

```
#All necessary imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
#Create same sample data (just made this up nothing specific)
data = {
    'From' : ['test@gmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com', 'test4@gmail.com'],
    'Subject' : ['Free Stuff', 'Buy Stuff', np.nan,'More Free Stuff', 'More Buy Stuff'],
    'Dates' : ['2022-05-18 01:00:00', '2022-05-18 03:00:00', '2022-05-19 08:00:00', '2022-05-20 01:00:00', '2022-05-21 10:00:00']
}

#Create a Dataframe with the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Set all nulls/nones/NaN to a blank string
df.fillna('', inplace = True)

#Set the Dates column to a date column with YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Create a column that will identify the what day the Dates column is on
df['Day'] = df['Dates'].dt.day_name()

#Write a np.select() to determine if the Subject column is null or if the Day column is on Friday or Saturday

#This is where you specify which days are spam days
list_of_spam_days = ['Friday', 'Saturday']

#List of conditions to test of true or false (np.nan is equivilent of a null)
condition_list = [df['Subject'] == '', df['Day'].isin(list_of_spam_days)]

#Mirroring the condition_list from before what should happen if the condition is true
true_list = ['Spam', 'Spam']

#Make a new column to which holds all of the results of our condition and true lists
#The final 'Not Spam' is the default if the condition list was not satisfied
df['Spam or Not Spam'] = np.select(condition_list, true_list, 'Not Spam')
df
```